# How to convert time object to datetime format in pandas (python)?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and practicing some basic functionalities. I have a CSV file which contains some data of every minute of some date. After reading CSV, `df.head()` gives the following result :

```
        Time            C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
0  2016-05-25 03:15:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
1  2016-05-25 03:16:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
2  2016-05-25 03:17:00  0   0   2   0   0   0  
3  2016-05-25 03:18:00  0   0   0   5   0   2
4  2016-05-25 03:19:00  0   0   0   0   0   5
```

I have used `parse_dates` option of `pd.read_csv`. Hence, Time is in `datetime64[ns]`format. Since, the date is the same I don't want to have that on my column. So, I use

```
df['Time']=df['Time'].dt.time
```

It does what I want but it changes the format to `object`, which I didn't want. Upon suggestions of some other answers, I  did the following :

```
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format="%H:%M:%S")
df['Time'].head()

0      1900-01-01 03:15:00
1      1900-01-01 03:16:00
2      1900-01-01 03:17:00
3      1900-01-01 03:18:00
4      1900-01-01 03:19:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This converted the column into `datetime64[ns]` but added an additional date. Is it possible to convert just time into `datetime64[ns]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. For datetimes always need dates.

But if need working with times, better is use [`timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html)s by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for strings `HH:MM:SS` with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
print (df)
      Time  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
0 03:15:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
1 03:16:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
2 03:17:00   0   0   2   0   0   0
3 03:18:00   0   0   0   5   0   2
4 03:19:00   0   0   0   0   0   5

print (df.dtypes)
Time    timedelta64[ns]
C1                int64
C2                int64
C3                int64
C4                int64
C5                int64
C6                int64
dtype: object
```